# Преобразование DOM объекта в строку, вывод и форматирование

Tags: javascript

Почему после преобразования в строку, показывает "23", а не "5"? И второй вопрос, почему toUpperCase() не показывает текст между тегами заглавными буквами?

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text = text.toString();
alert(text.length);
alert(text.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<div id="text">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: А чего вы вообще хотите добиться этим кодом? Вы понимаете, что у вас в переменной `text` объект dom? Если хотите работать с текстом, то и получайте текст `var text = document.getElementById('text').innerText;`

Comment: Разве нельзя преобразовать объект в строку?

Comment: @ikar зачем, если вы ожидаете получить только текст внутри тега???

Comment: Учусь! Думал так тоже можно получить текст.

Comment: @ikar, на самом деле, объект вполне и преобразовался в строку. Просто не так, как ожидал ты.

Comment: Спасибо! Это я уже заметил, подставив в конце кода alert(typeof text); //string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комментарий Pyramidhead к вопросу исчерпывающий. Я только распишу код:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text = text.innerHTML; // тут присваивайте свойство html объекта text, по сути - содержимое тега id="text" 
alert(text.length);
alert(text.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<div id="text">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: необходимую информацию стоит перенести из комментария в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть [спецификацию](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring), то можно отметить, что функция `toString`, если не переопределена, возвращает строку следующего вида:

```
[object `tag`]
```

Где `tag` зависит от типа объекта и значения специального свойства. В данном случае tag равен: *HTMLDivElement*.

Итоговая строка *"[object HTMLDivElement]"* и именно ее длина выводится.

---

Чтобы получить текст, нужно воспользоваться одним из свойств: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)